# dhcpd.conf "Configuration file errors encountered"

Tags: isc-dhcp

I want to set up the isc-dhcp-server, but the dhcp.conf file generates an error while testing with `dhcpd -t`:

```
...
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 6: expecting a parameter or declaration
authoritative;
              ^
Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
...
```

`cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for the ISC-DHCP Server 4.3.3
# Default sample file at /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.sample.conf


# global statements:
authoritative;
interface enp30s0;
option routers 192.168.100.1;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.178.1, 192.168.100.1;

subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
    range 192.168.100.10 192.168.100.110;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
}

# host declaration
host server {
    hardware ethernet 1c:c1:de:80:76:e8;
    fixed-address 192.168.100.10;
    option host-name "server";
}

host pc {
    hardware ethernet 1C:1B:0D:10:44:71;
    fixed-address 192.168.100.11;
    option host-name "PC";
}
```

Most of the file is copy & paste from the docs, so I have no idea where the issue can be...

Comment: No space in `255.255.255.0{` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to lie with the `interface enp30s0;` line. Since you refer to the options numerically, I don't think you need to specify the interface.

From the `dhcpd.conf` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf):

> option routers 204.254.239.1;
>
> Note that the address here is specified
>   numerically. This is not required - if you have a different domain
>   name for each interface on your router, it's perfectly legitimate to
>   use the domain name for that interface instead of the numeric address.
>   However, in many cases there may be only one domain name for all of a
>   router's IP addresses, and it would not be appropriate to use that
>   name here.

I went line by line recreating your `dhcpd.conf` with the example file and that is what broke it.

Here is my working version:

```
# cat /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.sample
# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option routers 192.168.100.1;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.178.1, 192.168.100.1;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.
subnet 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.100.10 192.168.100.110;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.
host server {
  hardware ethernet 1c:c1:de:80:76:e8;
  fixed-address 192.168.100.10;
  option host-name "server";
}

host pc {
    hardware ethernet 1C:1B:0D:10:44:71;
    fixed-address 192.168.100.11;
    option host-name "PC";
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help and have a nice day! :D